# MongoDB: Create unique index for nested document

Tags: arrays, mongodb, unique-index, mongodb-indexes

```
Array
(
    [_id] => 1
    [OrderId] => 123456_0203_2500001101518267176
    [Items] => Array
       0 =>  Array (
            [ItemId] => "123456"
            [ItemDesc] => "This Item numer 123456"
        ),
       1 =>  Array (
            [ItemId] => "123457"
            [ItemDesc] => "This Item numer 123457"
        ),


)

Array
(
    [_id] => 1
    [OrderId] => 123456_0203_2500001101518267199
    [Items] => Array
       0 =>  Array (
            [ItemId] => "123458"
            [ItemDesc] => "This Item numer 123458"
        ),
       1 =>  Array (
            [ItemId] => "123459"
            [ItemDesc] => "This Item numer 123459"
        ),


)
```

I want to make ItemId be unique in the document as well as across the document.

Unique index only provides uniqueness across the documents. But, I want to restrict repeating same ItemId within the document as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$addToSet` while inserting/updating your document. I don't think you will need indexes.

Example of using `$addToSet`

```
db.test.update(
   { _id: 1 },
   { $addToSet: {letters: [ "c", "d" ] } }
)
```

Details: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/addToSet/

Comment: I am not sure, whether this will be useful for me or not.This will be useful while updating a document, right?

Comment: Correct. and as of now there is no easy way to achieve this. I don't know  how are you using MongoDB. But there is an unique array plugin available in Mongoose https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-unique-array